# Objective-C Score counting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a flappy bird clone in my hands. And I am trying to understand why score is not counted correctly. It sometimes does not register a pipe. I am a total newbie:)

```
- (void) updateScore:(NSTimeInterval) currentTime
{
    for(int i=0;i<nbObstacles;i++){

        SKSpriteNode * topPipe = (SKSpriteNode *) topPipes[i];

        // Score, adapt font size
        if(X(topPipe) + WIDTH(topPipe)/2 > bird.position.x &&
           X(topPipe) + WIDTH(topPipe)/2 < bird.position.x + FLOOR_SCROLLING_SPEED){
            self.score +=1;
            scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",self.score];
            if(self.score>=10){
                scoreLabel.fontSize = 340;
                scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 120);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, every 3rd tube is not counting.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Score, adapt font size
    if(X(topPipe)+1 > bird.position.x &&
       X(topPipe) < bird.position.x + FLOOR_SCROLLING_SPEED){
        self.score +=1;
```

This solved everything